# ¿Como generar un evento para que se eliminen datos cada ciertos minutos?

Tags: mariadb, eventos

Tengo una base de datos llamada **appweb** y su tabla **usuarios**, quiero saber como puedo borrar los registros de la columna ***pdf*** cada cierto minutos[image: TABLA]

[image: DB]

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

```css
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `e_minutesss` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 MINUTE STARTS '2019-11-08 17:48:24'
 ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO 
BEGIN
  UPDATE user SET token = blank ;
  END



 UPDATE usuarios SET pdf = blank ;
 END
```

Pude actualizar la columna pdf estableciendo **blank** como texto alternativo
Muchas gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español... Que intentaste hasta ahora?? Por favor para mejorar tu pregunta lee [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Si lo pensas hacer desde mysql deberias primero:

habilitar el server

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Y luego crear tu evento, que sería así:

```
CREATE EVENT e_ActualizaPDF
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS ‘2019-01-01 00:00:00’
DO UPDATE usuarios SET pdf = 'nuevovalor'
```

Comment: Si quieres que evento no se detenga cada vez que reinicias el servidor te aconsejo que tu variable de event_scheduler la pongas en tu my.ini. De lo contrario cada que reinicias o detengas MySQL, tendras que ejecutar el comando SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON; para que tu evento empieze a ejecutarse

Comment: Muchas gracias por respondes, pero me aparece error de sintaxi :(, tengo mysql v10.1

Comment: @Erick cabe destacar que en MySQL la versión mas reciente es la 8, así que si dices que es la versión 10 entonces usas MariaDB

Comment: @Aprendiz, Perdón por mi falta, efectivamente, muchas gracias por ayudarme  y aporte en mi pregunta, saludos